# JSON or XML for parsing for Google Map API

Tags: xml, json

Can someone help me to find a easy way to parse XML?

I have an iOS 7 Application using Google Map API. I tried to learn this on my own.
I try to create an application that uses Web Services like Google Map.
These web services use HTTP requests to specific URLs, passing URL parameters as arguments to the services. Generally, these services return data in the HTTP request as either JSON or XML for parsing and/or processing by my application.

I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try this:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ono is pretty straightforward:

```objective-c
ONOXMLDocument *document = [ONOXMLDocument XMLDocumentWithData:data error:&error];

for (ONOXMLElement *element in document.rootElement.children) {
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", element.tag, element.attributes);
}
```

As is GDataXMLDocument:

```objective-c
NSData* xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];

GDataXMLDocument *document = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil];

NSArray* entries = [document.rootElement elementsForName:@"entry"];

for(GDataXMLElement* element in entries)
{
    published = [element elementsForName:@"published"][0];
}
```

or NSXMLParser:

```objective-c
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "author" {
        self.item.author = self.foundCharacters;
    }

    if elementName == "description" {
        self.item.desc = self.foundCharacters;
    }

    if elementName == "item" {
        let tempItem = Item();
        tempItem.author = self.item.author;
        tempItem.desc = self.item.desc;
        tempItem.tag = self.item.tag;
        self.items.append(tempItem);
        self.item.tag.removeAll();
    }
    self.foundCharacters = ""
}
```

**References**

- [Parsing using GDataXML with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690463/1113772)
- [A Beginner’s Guide to XML Parsing in Swift](http://leaks.wanari.com/2016/08/24/xml-parsing-swift/)
- [NSXMLElement: elementsForName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmlelement/1388329-elementsforname)
- [Ono: A sensible way to deal with XML & HTML for iOS & OS X](https://github.com/mattt/Ono)
- [NSXMLNode: XPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmlnode/1409826-xpath)
- [SeismicXML: Using NSXMLParser to parse XML documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [SampleCode: XMLPerformance](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Why don't just use [Google's Api Clients](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/wiki)?